# Why doesn't Tensorflow automatically handle hidden states of recurrent cells?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am going through couple of Tensorflow examples that use LSTM cells and trying to understand the purpose of `initial_state` variable that is used in one implementation but not in the other for some unknown reason.

For example [PTB example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py) uses it as:

```
self._initial_state = cell.zero_state(config.batch_size, data_type())
state = self._initial_state
```

where it represents hidden state transitions and used to keep the hidden state intact during batch training. This variable should be zeroed between the epochs naturally. And yet some recurrent [Bi-LSTM models](https://github.com/guillaumegenthial/sequence_tagging) don't use `initial_state` at all which makes you think that either it is somehow done by Tensorflow behind-the-scenes or not necessary at all hence the confusion. So, why do some recurrent  models use it and others don't? In Torch for example, same mechanism is as simple as:

```
local params, grad_params = model:getParameters()
-- start training loop
while epoch < max_epoch do
   for mini_batch in training_data do
    (...)
    grad_params:zero()
   end
end
```

The hidden state is handled by the framework no need for all that really clunky stuff or am I missing something here. Can you please explain how does it work in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, it it appears to be specific setup for Tensorflow PTB model which is supposed to be running not only with single LSTM cells but with several ones (who would even try to train it on more than 2 cells I wonder). For that it needs to keep track of `c` and `h` tensors between the cells and thus the `_initial_state` variable.  It also is supposed to be running in parallel over several GPUs as well, continue if interrupted etc. And that is why PTB example code looks ugly and overengineered to a newcomer.